# How can i get the path to the common Desktop and Start Menu dirs in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-2.0

I'm using .NET 2.0. I noticed that there doesn't seem to be a [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) member for the common Desktop and common Start Menu folders.

i would prefer a way that doesn't involve loading shell32.dll and using SHGetSpecialFolderPath

Comment: I'd love to know a better way than p/invoke myself :)

Comment: Common meaning for all users. my specific use case is that i want to dump a shortcut that shows up on all users' desktop

Comment: I am surprised you are not getting the `Environment.SpecialFolders` enum...it could be the intellisense is slightly unhinged. However, in VS 2008, it works perfectly. Weird..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use P/Invoke... 0x19 corresponds to the Common Desktop enumeration, 0x16 corresponds to the Common Start Menu

```
    public static string GetCommonDesktopFolder()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(260);
        SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, 0x19, IntPtr.Zero, 0, sb); // CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern int SHGetFolderPath(
                IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder, IntPtr hToken,
                uint dwFlags, StringBuilder pszPath);

}
```

Comment: thanks John, sorry i didn't get my edit about SHGetFolderPath in before you started responding! I'm wondering if there is a ".NET Way" to do it

Comment: I'm assuming it's in the registry somewhere, but I don't know for sure.  That may be the route you want to explore if your willing to take the risk of accessing undocumented info.

Comment: sounds like i'm better off just using the shell32 way.

Answer (score 4):

This code snippet uses the registry to access the common desktop:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
key = key.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders");
String commonDesktop = key.GetValue("Common Desktop").ToString();
```

From [here](http://www.sorrowman.org/c-sharp-programmer/small-tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try casting 0x19 and 0x16 to Environment.SpecialFolder to pass to Environment.GetFolderPath

Comment: throws an exception: "Illegal enum value"